RK4 acoustic wave equation
I am trying to modify a code to include a runge kutta time stepping scheme. The original code was not written by me but my motive is to eliminate the pygame library and make it as easy as possible while incorporating RK4. Below are my codes
import pygame
import numpy as np
import random
import math
import time

hs = 1   # spatial step width
ts = 1   # time step width
dimx = 700   # width of the simulation domain
dimy = 700   # height of the simulation domain
cellsize = 1 # display size of a cell in pixel


def create_arrays():
    global velocity
    global tau
    global kappa
    global gauss_peak
    global u
    
    # The three dimensional simulation grid 
    u = np.zeros((3, dimx, dimy))       

    # A field containing the velocity for each cell
    velocity = np.zeros((dimx, dimy))   

    # A field containing the factor for the Laplace Operator that  combines Velocity and Grid Constants for the Wave Equation
    tau  = np.zeros((dimx, dimy))       

    # A field containing the factor for the Laplace Operator that combines Velocity and Grid Constants for the Boundary Condition 
    kappa = np.zeros((dimx, dimy))      

    # Create a template for a gauss peak to use as a rain drop model
    sz = 10
    sigma = 2.4
    xx, yy = np.meshgrid(range(-sz, sz), range(-sz, sz))
    gauss_peak = np.zeros((sz, sz))
    gauss_peak = 300 / (sigma*2*math.pi) * (math.sqrt(2*math.pi)) * np.exp(- 0.5 * ((xx**2+yy**2)/(sigma**2)))


def set_initial_conditions(u):
    global velocity
    global tau
    global kappa
    global gauss_peak

    velocity[0:dimx,0:dimy] = 0.3            # 0.39 m/s Wave velocity of shallow water waves (lambda 0.1, depth 0.1)
    velocity[220:300,100:dimy-100] = 0.2      # will be set to a constant value of tau
    velocity[300:400,100:dimy-100] = 0.1      # will be set to a constant value of tau
    velocity[0:dimx, 300:] = 0.4     # will be set to a constant value of tau

    # compute tau and kappa from the velocity field
    tau = ( (velocity*ts) / hs )**2
    kappa = ts * velocity / hs  

    # Place a single gaussian peak at the center of the simulation
    put_gauss_peak(u, int(dimx/2), int(dimy/2), 10)


def put_gauss_peak(u, x : int, y : int, height):
    """Place a gauss shaped peak into the simulation domain.
    
        This function will put a gauss shaped peak at position x,y 
        of the simulation domain.
    """
    w,h = gauss_peak.shape
    w = int(w/2)
    h = int(h/2)

    use_multipole = False
    if use_multipole:
        # Multipole
        dist = 3
        u[0:2, x-w-dist:x+w-dist, y-h:y+h] += height * gauss_peak
        u[0:2, x-w:x+w, y-h+dist:y+h+dist] -= height * gauss_peak
        u[0:2, x-w+dist:x+w+dist, y-h:y+h] += height * gauss_peak
        u[0:2, x-w:x+w, y-h-dist:y+h-dist] -= height * gauss_peak        
    else:
        # simple peak
        u[0:2, x-w:x+w, y-h:y+h] += height * gauss_peak


def update(u : any, method : int):
    u[2] = u[1]
    u[1] = u[0]
    
    if method==0: 
        boundary_size = 1

        # This is the second order scheme with a laplacian that takes the diagonals into account.
        # The resulting wave shape will look a bit better under certain conditions but the accuracy 
        # is still low. In most cases you will hardly see a difference to #1
        u[0, 1:dimx-1, 1:dimy-1] = tau[1:dimx-1, 1:dimy-1] \
                                   * (    0.25 * u[1, 0:dimx-2, 0:dimy-2] # c-1, r-1 =>  1
                                        + 0.5  * u[1, 1:dimx-1, 0:dimy-2] # c,   r-1 =>  1
                                        + 0.25 * u[1, 2:dimx  , 0:dimy-2] # c+1, r-1 =>  1

                                        + 0.5  * u[1, 0:dimx-2, 1:dimy-1] # c-1, r =>  1
                                        - 3    * u[1, 1:dimx-1, 1:dimy-1] # c,   r => -8
                                        + 0.5  * u[1, 2:dimx  , 1:dimy-1] # c+1, r =>  1

                                        + 0.25 * u[1, 0:dimx-2, 2:dimy]   # c-1, r+1 =>  1
                                        + 0.5  * u[1, 1:dimx-1, 2:dimy]   # c,   r+1 =>  1
                                        + 0.25 * u[1, 2:dimx  , 2:dimy]   # c+1, r+1 =>  1
                                     ) \
                                + 2 * u[1, 1:dimx-1, 1:dimy-1] \
                                -     u[2, 1:dimx-1, 1:dimy-1]
    elif method==1: # ok, (4)th Order https://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1988-51-184/S0025-5718-1988-0935077-0/S0025-5718-1988-0935077-0.pdf; Page 702
        boundary_size = 2
        u[0, 2:dimx-2, 2:dimy-2]  = tau[2:dimx-2, 2:dimy-2]\
                                    * ( -  1 * u[1, 2:dimx-2, 0:dimy-4]  # c    , r-2 => -1
                                        + 16 * u[1, 2:dimx-2, 1:dimy-3]  # c    , r-1 => 16                                       

                                        -  1 * u[1, 0:dimx-4, 2:dimy-2]  # c - 2, r => -1
                                        + 16 * u[1, 1:dimx-3, 2:dimy-2]  # c - 1, r => 16
                                        - 60 * u[1, 2:dimx-2, 2:dimy-2]  # c    , r => -60
                                        + 16 * u[1, 3:dimx-1, 2:dimy-2]  # c+1  , r => 16
                                        -  1 * u[1, 4:dimx,   2:dimy-2]  # c+2  , r => -1

                                        + 16 * u[1, 2:dimx-2, 3:dimy-1]  # c    , r+1 => 16                                       
                                        - 1  * u[1, 2:dimx-2, 4:dimy]    # c    , r+2 => -1 
                                        ) / 12 \
                                    + 2*u[1, 2:dimx-2, 2:dimy-2] \
                                    -   u[2, 2:dimx-2, 2:dimy-2]         
    elif method==2: # ok, (6th) https://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1988-51-184/S0025-5718-1988-0935077-0/S0025-5718-1988-0935077-0.pdf; Page 702
        boundary_size = 3
        u[0, 3:dimx-3, 3:dimy-3]  = tau[3:dimx-3, 3:dimy-3]\
                                    * (     2 * u[1, 3:dimx-3, 0:dimy-6]  # c,   r-3
                                        -  27 * u[1, 3:dimx-3, 1:dimy-5]  # c,   r-2
                                        + 270 * u[1, 3:dimx-3, 2:dimy-4]  # c,   r-1

                                        +   2 * u[1, 0:dimx-6, 3:dimy-3] # c - 3, r
                                        -  27 * u[1, 1:dimx-5, 3:dimy-3] # c - 2, r
                                        + 270 * u[1, 2:dimx-4, 3:dimy-3] # c - 1, r
                                        - 980 * u[1, 3:dimx-3, 3:dimy-3] # c    , r
                                        + 270 * u[1, 4:dimx-2, 3:dimy-3] # c + 1, r
                                        -  27 * u[1, 5:dimx-1, 3:dimy-3] # c + 2, r
                                        +   2 * u[1, 6:dimx,   3:dimy-3] # c + 3, r

                                        + 270 * u[1, 3:dimx-3, 4:dimy-2]  # c  , r+1
                                        -  27 * u[1, 3:dimx-3, 5:dimy-1]  # c  , r+2
                                        +   2 * u[1, 3:dimx-3, 6:dimy  ]  # c  , r+3
                                        ) / 180 \
                                    + 2*u[1, 3:dimx-3, 3:dimy-3] \
                                    -   u[2, 3:dimx-3, 3:dimy-3]  
    elif method==3: # ok, (8th) https://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1988-51-184/S0025-5718-1988-0935077-0/S0025-5718-1988-0935077-0.pdf; Page 702
        boundary_size = 4
        u[0, 4:dimx-4, 4:dimy-4]  = tau[4:dimx-4, 4:dimy-4]\
                                    * ( -  1/560 * u[1, 4:dimx-4, 0:dimy-8]  # c,   r-4
                                        +  8/315 * u[1, 4:dimx-4, 1:dimy-7]  # c,   r-3
                                        -    1/5 * u[1, 4:dimx-4, 2:dimy-6]  # c,   r-2
                                        +    8/5 * u[1, 4:dimx-4, 3:dimy-5]  # c,   r-1

                                        - 1/560  * u[1, 0:dimx-8, 4:dimy-4]  # c - 4, r
                                        + 8/315  * u[1, 1:dimx-7, 4:dimy-4]  # c - 3, r
                                        -   1/5  * u[1, 2:dimx-6, 4:dimy-4]  # c - 2, r
                                        +   8/5  * u[1, 3:dimx-5, 4:dimy-4]  # c - 1, r
                                        - 410/72 * u[1, 4:dimx-4, 4:dimy-4]  # c    , r
                                        +   8/5  * u[1, 5:dimx-3, 4:dimy-4]  # c + 1, r
                                        -   1/5  * u[1, 6:dimx-2, 4:dimy-4]  # c + 2, r
                                        + 8/315  * u[1, 7:dimx-1, 4:dimy-4]  # c + 3, r
                                        - 1/560  * u[1, 8:dimx  , 4:dimy-4]  # c + 4, r

                                        +    8/5 * u[1, 4:dimx-4, 5:dimy-3]  # c  , r+1
                                        -    1/5 * u[1, 4:dimx-4, 6:dimy-2]  # c  , r+2
                                        +  8/315 * u[1, 4:dimx-4, 7:dimy-1]  # c  , r+3
                                        -  1/560 * u[1, 4:dimx-4, 8:dimy  ]  # c  , r+4
                                        ) \
                                    + 2*u[1, 4:dimx-4, 4:dimy-4] \
                                    -   u[2, 4:dimx-4, 4:dimy-4]  

    # Absorbing Boundary Conditions:
    mur = True
    if mur==True:
        update_boundary(u, boundary_size)


def update_boundary(u, sz) -> None:
    """Update the boundary cells. 
    
        Implement MUR boundary conditions. This represents an open boundary were waves can leave the
        simulation domain with little remaining reflection artifacts. Although this is of a low error 
        order it is good enough for this simulation.
    """
    c = dimx-1
    u[0, dimx-sz-1:c, 1:dimy-1] = u[1,  dimx-sz-2:c-1, 1:dimy-1] + (kappa[dimx-sz-1:c, 1:dimy-1]-1)/(kappa[ dimx-sz-1:c, 1:dimy-1]+1) * (u[0,  dimx-sz-2:c-1,1:dimy-1] - u[1, dimx-sz-1:c,1:dimy-1])
    
    c = 0
    u[0, c:sz, 1:dimy-1]        = u[1, c+1:sz+1, 1:dimy-1]       + (kappa[c:sz, 1:dimy-1]-1)/(kappa[c:sz, 1:dimy-1]+1)                * (u[0, c+1:sz+1,1:dimy-1]       - u[1,c:sz,1:dimy-1])

    r = dimy-1
    u[0, 1:dimx-1, dimy-1-sz:r] = u[1, 1:dimx-1, dimy-2-sz:r-1] + (kappa[1:dimx-1, dimy-1-sz:r]-1)/(kappa[1:dimx-1, dimy-1-sz:r]+1) * (u[0, 1:dimx-1, dimy-2-sz:r-1] - u[1, 1:dimx-1, dimy-1-sz:r])

    r = 0
    u[0, 1:dimx-1, r:sz] = u[1, 1:dimx-1, r+1:sz+1] + (kappa[1:dimx-1, r:sz]-1)/(kappa[1:dimx-1, r:sz]+1) * (u[0, 1:dimx-1, r+1:sz+1] - u[1, 1:dimx-1, r:sz])


def put_gauss_peak(u, x : int, y : int, height):
    """Place a gauss shaped peak into the simulation domain.
    
        This function will put a gauss shaped peak at position x,y 
        of the simulation domain.
    """
    w,h = gauss_peak.shape
    w = int(w/2)
    h = int(h/2)

    use_multipole = False
    if use_multipole:
        # Multipole
        dist = 3
        u[0:2, x-w-dist:x+w-dist, y-h:y+h] += height * gauss_peak
        u[0:2, x-w:x+w, y-h+dist:y+h+dist] -= height * gauss_peak
        u[0:2, x-w+dist:x+w+dist, y-h:y+h] += height * gauss_peak
        u[0:2, x-w:x+w, y-h-dist:y+h-dist] -= height * gauss_peak        
    else:
        # simple peak
        u[0:2, x-w:x+w, y-h:y+h] += height * gauss_peak


# def place_raindrops(u):
#     if (random.random()<0.003):
#         w,h = gauss_peak.shape
#         x = int(random.randrange(w+w/2, dimx-h-h/2))
#         y = int(random.randrange(w+w/2, dimy-h-h/2))

#         height = 2
#         put_gauss_peak(u, x, y, height)


def draw_waves(display, u, data, offset):
    global velocity
    global font

    data[1:dimx, 1:dimy, 0] = 255 - np.clip((u[0, 1:dimx, 1:dimy]>0) * 10 * u[0, 1:dimx, 1:dimy]+u[1, 1:dimx, 1:dimy]+u[2, 1:dimx, 1:dimy], 0, 255)
    data[1:dimx, 1:dimy, 1] = 255 - np.clip(np.abs(u[0, 1:dimx, 1:dimy]) * 10, 0, 255)
    data[1:dimx, 1:dimy, 2] = 255 - np.clip((u[0, 1:dimx, 1:dimy]<=0) * -10 * u[0, 1:dimx, 1:dimy] + u[1, 1:dimx, 1:dimy] + u[2, 1:dimx, 1:dimy], 0, 255) 

    surf = pygame.surfarray.make_surface(data)
    display.blit(pygame.transform.scale(surf, (dimx * cellsize, dimy * cellsize)), offset)    


def draw_text(display, fps, tick):
    global font

    text_surface = font.render('2D Wave Equation - Explicit Euler (Radiating Boundary Conditions)', True, (0, 0, 40))
    display.blit(text_surface, (5,5))

    text_surface = font.render(f'FPS: {fps:.1f}; t={tick*ts:.2f} s; area={dimx*hs}x{dimy*hs} m', True, (0, 0, 40))
    display.blit(text_surface, (5, dimy*cellsize - 20))


def main():
    global font

    pygame.init()
    pygame.font.init()
                   
    font = pygame.font.SysFont('Consolas', 15)    
    display = pygame.display.set_mode((dimx*cellsize, dimy*cellsize))
    pygame.display.set_caption("Solving the 2d Wave Equation")

    create_arrays()
    set_initial_conditions(u)

    image1data = np.zeros((dimx, dimy, 3), dtype = np.uint8 )

    tick = 0
    last_tick = 0
    fps = 0
    start_time = time.time()

    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                return

        tick = tick + 1

        current_time = time.time() 
        if current_time - start_time > 0.5:
            fps = (tick-last_tick) / (current_time - start_time) 
            start_time = time.time()
            last_tick = tick

        # place_raindrops(u)

        update(u, 3)
        draw_waves(display, u,  image1data, (0,0))
        draw_text(display, fps, tick)

        pygame.display.update()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


I would like to know how to modify the above. Any assistance would be helpful. The code above makes use of the euler time stepping scheme however i would like to advance and implement the RK4, RK5, RK7 time stepping schemes
